# Запуск javascript-обработчика по нажатию Enter

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть текстовое поле и функция (javascript), которая обрабатывает содержимое формы.
Как запускать эту функцию, когда пользователь нажимает клавишу Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

```
$('input selector').on('keydown', function( e ) {
  if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    whenEnterPressed();
  }
});
```

Comment: В ответы ! а вообще спасибо )